# Google Calendar API Sample

Tags: android

Super Newbie question I downloaded the google api java client samples, I'm trying to use the calendar sample. I inserted my api key in the clientcredentials.java but I'm still getting a 403 forbidden error limit exceeded yet I haven't used the app once is there something I'm missing the developers pages say that it should load up on my phone but I cant get it to do so! I'm about ready to snap my laptop in half a simple tutorial would be greatly appreciated I haven't found one straight foward explanation on how to use it and I have been googling since about 5:30 this morning!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What do you want to do with the calendar api?

Comment: I just want to run it to test the application if I like it I will incorporate it in an app that I'm playing with.